# what is "this" in setOnClickListenner in Android

Tags: android-button

I'm new to Android and I know this is very common question. I tried to look for answers but it didn't satisfy my curiosity. Supposed that I have code below to define a listener for a button in Android. I'm still confusing about the this . I know "this" refers to the current instance but in this case, what does "this" refer to ? Does it point to the instance btnSave or which else objects ? Why can it replace the argument (new OnClickListener()) 
Supposed that I have two identical button. How does the method Onclick know which one is clicked  ??? Can someone clarify the purpose of "this" in an broader situation ?

```
 Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

 public void onClick(View v) {

    //Do something in here 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `this` refers to reference to the current object, the container that had the `btnSave` in this case. The intention is the the container will listen to `Click` events taking place on the button to take further action through the listener method i.e. `onClick`.

Comment: So you mean that "this" points to the activity class which contains the container ???